# I need to create a line around an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[example http://www.uppic.org/thumb-5558_4FA283FC.jpg](http://www.uppic.org/thumb-5558_4FA283FC.jpg)

If I need to create a line around an element, what should I do?

Comment: Is this a serious question???

Comment: Wait,  red line or red lines?.  If you want line , put that element in a div using jquery.  and give a padded border for it as well.

Comment: @ngen why put that element in a div???

Comment: red lines, I think jquery can make it but I don't know

Comment: To give it a padded border!. Where else will you put it?. But what he actually want is totally ':O' for me. :|

Comment: @facebook-100001103441097 if you could tell us what's your intention or what's the actual logic for putting those blank red rectangles around the image , then we might be able to help.

Comment: this example.http://upic.me/i/r3/sexam.png

Comment: Just the box, or also the lines that extend beyond the box around the picture of the woman?  It's frustrating to get a vaguely worded question like this.  Lots of people would love to help you if you take a moment to write a detailed question that is as explicit as possible about the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS's `outline` or `border`. They work like this:

```
outline:1px solid blue;
```

Where the thickness, style, and color can be pretty much anything.

[More info on outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/outline)
[Border spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-shorthands)

Answer (score 1):

Use `style="border:1px solid black;"`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding  `.css('border','1px solid #000');` for that selector?.

Comment: sorry! I mean red line not black line.

Answer (score 0):

In it's CSS file use:

```
#Element_id {
               border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

or if the element is used multiple times, it should be a class, so use:

```
.Element_class {
               border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Or if you want the red lines, create multiple divs (in your case 9) and edit their individual borders to acheave this effect.